# Rolling Window Slider R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to average weather data using slider functions. I essentially want to bin by 10 day increments. So days 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30. Here are some example data:

```
historicalWeatherSummary <- structure(list(Historical_date = structure(c(3286, 3287, 3288, 
3289, 3290, 3291), class = "Date"), daily_min_temp_daytime = c(25.29, 
33.28, 39.33, 14.02, -2.47, 1.02), daily_min_temp_nighttime = c(25.45, 
29.82, 36.66, 6.3, -2.72, 1.18)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    Historical_date = structure(c(3286, 3287, 3288, 3289, 3290, 
    3291), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I am using the following code, which I must not be using correctly.

```
tenDayWindows <- historicalWeatherSummary %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Historical_date) %>%
  mutate(`1to10_avg_min_daytime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_daytime, ~mean(.x), .after = 10, .complete = TRUE),
         `1to10_avg_min_nighttime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_nighttime, ~mean(.x), .after = 10, .complete = TRUE),
         `11to20_avg_min_daytime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_daytime, ~mean(.x), .step = 10, .after = 10,  .complete = TRUE),
         `11to20_avg_min_nighttime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_nighttime, ~mean(.x), .after = 10, .step = 10, .complete = TRUE),
         `21to30_avg_min_daytime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_daytime, ~mean(.x), .after = 10, .step = 20, .complete = TRUE),
         `21to30_avg_min_nighttime_temp` = slide_dbl(daily_min_temp_nighttime, ~mean(.x), .after = 10, .step = 20, .complete = TRUE),
         
         )
```

My thought process was that it would calculate the mean of the 10 rows after a step of 10 and a step of 20. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am looking the averages from days 1 to 10, 11 to 20 and 21 to 30 after the specified date.

EDIT - Added image example:

[image]

Comment: if you want days 1-10, 11-20, etc, then I think "rolling" is not the term you want but "tumbling" instead

Comment: or ... perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Your use of `mutate` suggests that for each date (one row), you will add your new columns, so that `11to20_*` will reference data 10-20 rows previously, is that right?

Comment: I am using mutate to add columns for each span. So imagine looking at historical weather data from 1/1/2020. I would want the average temp from 1/1/2020 to 1/10/2020 in a column. Then the average temp from 1/11/2020 to 1/20/2020 in another column. This would all be for the historical date of 1/1/2020. To give perspective - I am trying to create a model that will help estimate yield and days to harvest of plants. So 1/1/2020 would be my plant date and then want 10 day averages in a column

Comment: Your data is not currently structured with "spans", it is "by date", should you be `summarize`ing instead so that each row is a span? And ... I'm assuming that `Historical_date` is your "plant date"?

Comment: The spans should be relative to the date. I am going to try to add a diagram to help

Comment: What do the different columns in your figure represent?

Comment: Is the question like "For Jan 1, what is a) the avg for jan 1-10, b) the avg for jan 11-20, c) the avg for jan 21-30,   and then do the same starting from jan 2, etc?"

Comment: @JonSpring - Yes, so long as starting on Jan 2 you use the average from Jan 2-11 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use something like this.

```
historicalWeatherSummary %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Historical_date) %>%
  mutate(across(2:3, ~slider::slide_index_dbl(.x, Historical_date, mean , .after = 9), .names = "d1_10_{.col}"),
         across(2:3, ~slider::slide_index_dbl(.x, Historical_date, mean , .before = -2, .after = 19), .names = "d11_20_{.col}"),
         across(2:3, ~slider::slide_index_dbl(.x, Historical_date, mean , .before = -3, .after = 29), .names = "d21_30_{.col}"))
```

1. I'd ungroup first, so each calculation can see other rows
2. `slider` needs pre-sorted data, so I add an arrange step in case the data might not be entirely chronological
3. `slide_index_dbl` uses the `Historical_date` column to calculate date ranges, useful if your data potentially has gaps.
4. We can use the `.before` parameter with a negative number if we want the start range to begin *after* the current date. I used `-2` and `-3` for demonstration purposes on the example data, but you'd probably want `-10` and `-20`.
5. I use `.after = 9` in the first case to use a window of ten days, reflecting the current date through the one 9 days later.

---

Result

```
  Historical_date daily_min_temp_daytime daily_min_temp_nighttime d1_10_daily_min_temp_daytime d1_10_daily_min_temp_nighttime d11_20_daily_min_temp_daytime d11_20_daily_min_temp_nighttime d21_30_daily_min_temp_daytime d21_30_daily_min_temp_nighttime
  <date>                           <dbl>                    <dbl>                        <dbl>                          <dbl>                         <dbl>                           <dbl>                         <dbl>                           <dbl>
1 1978-12-31                       25.3                     25.4                        18.4                            16.1                         13.0                             10.4                          4.19                             1.59
2 1979-01-01                       33.3                     29.8                        17.0                            14.2                          4.19                             1.59                        -0.725                           -0.77
3 1979-01-02                       39.3                     36.7                        13.0                            10.4                         -0.725                           -0.77                         1.02                             1.18
4 1979-01-03                       14.0                      6.3                         4.19                            1.59                         1.02                             1.18                       NaN                              NaN   
5 1979-01-04                       -2.47                    -2.72                       -0.725                          -0.77                       NaN                              NaN                          NaN                              NaN   
6 1979-01-05                        1.02                     1.18                        1.02                            1.18                       NaN                              NaN                          NaN                              NaN
```

Comment: Best part is - all I had to do was adjust the across and it automatically added all my other columns. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to group your data such that the first 10 rows belong to group 1, rows 11 to 20 belong to group 2, rows 21 to 30 belong to group 3 etc.

If this is the case, you can simply use `group_by` and `summarise` to get your desired result:

```
historicalWeatherSummary %>%
  group_by(my_group = (row_number() -1L) %/% 10L) %>%
  summarise(
    period_start = min(Historical_date),
    period_end = max(Historical_date),
    avg_min_temp_daytime = mean(daily_min_temp_daytime),
    avg_min_temp_nighttime = mean(daily_min_temp_nighttime),
    )
```

Note that `(row_number() -1L) %/% 10L` groups data exactly as I described above.